# Test two database data is identical or not

Tags: testing, database-testing

For a testing projects I need to test is databases are working as required or not; as well as need to check that given two databases, the data in DB  are identical or not.
So, is there any pre-defined algorithm for preforming this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define what is identical. Is it schema, data or both? If schema, is it only tables or all elements including functions/procedures/views etc.

If you would use jdbc, then start with schema revealing functions and compare and contrast the objects one by one. Then repeat the same for the data inside the tables.

You can take advantage of the OpenSource projects to read the schema details.

Comment: I need to check is data is identical or not